# Android Button Background draw9patch not showing text

Tags: java, android, android-button

I have successfully created draw9patch image for button and its stretching accordingly,
But its not showing button text.

```
<Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLocationDirection"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="38sp"
                android:background="@drawable/directions_e"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/location_direction"
                android:paddingRight="10sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@color/log_display_color"
                 />
```

Where directions_e is draw9patch image.

Comment: Have you specified the content area of your 9-patch image correctly? Have a look at the documentation here for more details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: will it work when setting layout_width to wrap_content? and remove paddingRight attribute? and could u post your 9-patch?

Comment: I tried setting layout_width as wrap_content and removing paddingRight, but sitill its not showing text.

Comment: Solved, I was drawing wrong 9-patch for image.